# How to use the new checkbox funcionality with Xamarin 4.1.1?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to user the new checkbox functionality that was implemented in Xamarin 4.1.0.

NuGet tells me that i use the current version 4.1.1

When i try to do something like that:

```
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox { IsChecked = true };
```

Visual Studio keeps telling me, that the class Checkbox is not found, and asks me to use Android.Widget. Thats not what i want.

Any ideas what could be wrong? Does it work for others?

Comment: Could you share a little project that reproduces this? It should just work like that :)

Comment: The latest version is Monday, July 1, 2019 - Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.555618 (4.1.0), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.1/4.1.0#monday-july-1-2019---xamarinforms-410555618-410, I can not found any information about 4.1.1, please convert back you version to the 4.1.0.555618.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and sorry.. i mixed the azure with the xamarin NuGet... -.-

Updated Xamarin to the newest and it works.